# What do the little flags on these martian wind speed data points mean?

Tags: meteorology, mars

According to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34307/12102) the weather at the InSight lander on Mars can now be seen online at https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/weather/ This includes the wind speed and I believe the direction (if that's what those little flags mean).

**Question:** But I'm not sure so I'd like to ask; what do the little flags on these martian wind speed data points mean?

[image]

---

A bit of history...

From the question [Was the telltale on the Mars Phoenix Lander used for meteorology? Why not a hot wire anemometer instead?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21680/12102)

[image]

**above:** GIF from images transmitted from Mars. From the [The Telltale project](http://marslab.au.dk/research/instrument-development/the-telltale-project/) page on the [Mars Simulation Laboratory](http://marslab.au.dk/). Also [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120220080017/http://www.marslab.dk/TelltaleProject.html).

Comment: Related: [How does InSight measure wind speed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34404/12102)

Comment: @gansub yep! https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/22199/of-wind-and-dust-devils-on-mars/?site=insight

Comment: @gansub one step at a time, let's see if there is data: [Does Mars have a known “prevailing wind” direction?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34412/12102)

Comment: @gansub The 750 GeV "blip" at CERN [generated 500 scholarly papers with theoretical explanations](https://cosmosmagazine.com/physics/tantalising-lhc-blip-not-a-particle-after-all) before it was found that it didn't exist. Start with data.

Comment: @gansub https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34424/12102

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They indicate wind direction (given by the long line or "barb") and speed (given by the shorter flags extending from each barb). In the same linked page you can read:

> The barbs extending from each wind speed data point indicate the
>   compass direction of the wind (e.g., a wind blowing from the north
>   will have a barb straight up above the point; a wind blowing from the
>   west will have a barb off to the left). Full and half flags extending
>   from the barbs indicate the wind speed, with each half flag
>   representing approximately 2.5 meters per second. A circle in place of
>   a barb indicates a wind speed less than 2.5 meters per second.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer! I am remiss for not noticing it was on the page already. I wonder if there is any utility to modulating the barb size on data points that *already indicate* the wind speed, or if it's done simply because it's standard. Also wondering if 2.5 m/s per half-barb is standard, or if these chars always need a half-barb scale explanation. Do you think those need a separate question?

Comment: Yes the flags are redundant in a speed plot, but as you say it is used because it is standard in meteorograms (barbs that include flags). The flags also make a bit more intuitive to figure out the direction the barb is pointing to.
The speed of 2.5 m/s per flag is not standard (at least not in the NOAA GFS meteorograms that I often use).

Comment: the directional arrows and flags are a standard for most meteorological services around the world.